# AutoFilter in excel in descending order and not empty with vba

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to auto filter a list in excel, but I am experiencing some problem with filtering it ascending and not empty rows.

I have an excel sheet(ws1) with something like 50 columns and a few hundred rows.

So I loop through all columns in ws1 and compare it with a text I have specified in a second excel sheet(ws2), if this is X,Ascending,descending,Free text,not empty for the respective column I would apply that filter for it.

So mostly it works, if it X it display the column:

```
  For i = 1 To lColumn1
        If IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) Then
            ws1.Cells(rowheader1, i).Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            ws1.Cells(rowheader1, i).Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            On Error Resume Next
            If Not UCase(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) = "X" Then
```

For descending it does not apply the filter:

```
 ElseIf UCase(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) = "DESCENDING" Then
 With ws1.AutoFilter.Sort
     .SortFields.Add key:=Range(Cells(rowheader1, i), Cells(lastRowVal, i)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
                                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
      .Apply
  End With
 ws1.ApplyFilter
```

lastRowVal  is the last row in the sheet : lastRowVal = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row (maybe use usedrange instead?)

also I would like to apply a sorting crietria which display all rows which are not blank:

```
 ElseIf UCase(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) = "NOTEMPTY" Then
 With ws1.AutoFilter.Sort
     .SortFields.Add key:=Range(Cells(rowheader1, i), Cells(lastRowVal, i)), SortOn:=xlSortOnNONBLANKS, _
                                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
      .Apply
  End With
 ws1.ApplyFilter
```

below is the almost the entire code for the macro:

```
Sub Custom_Button_Click(Optional ByVal simulateButton As Boolean = False)
    Dim columnHeader As String
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim wb, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim closefilter As Boolean
    closefilter = True

    'set the worksheet we will be dealing with
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("List")
    closefilter = FileHandling.setWorksheetFilter(wb2, ws2)

    On Error Resume Next

    Call Unhide_All_Columns
    ws1.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    If Not simulateButton Then
        columnHeader = CStr(ws1.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name)

        If Not ThisWorkbook.buttonActive = "" Then
            ws1.Shapes.Range(Array(ThisWorkbook.buttonActive)).Select
            With Selection.Font
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With
        End If

        If Not columnHeader = "ShowGUI" Then
            ws1.Shapes.Range(Array(columnHeader)).Select
            With Selection.Font
                .ColorIndex = 50
            End With
        End If

        If Not columnHeader = "ShowGUI" Then
            ThisWorkbook.buttonActive = columnHeader
        End If
    Else
        columnHeader = ThisWorkbook.buttonActive
    End If


    Dim rng As Range


    lastRowVal = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
    'Set range from which to determine largest value
    Set rng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lastRowVal, 1))


    rowheader1 = counter.getHeaderRow(ws1)

    columFilter = HelpFunctions.getColumn(columnHeader, ws2, 1)

    lColumn1 = ws1.Cells(rowheader1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    For i = 1 To lColumn1
        If IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) Then
            ws1.Cells(rowheader1, i).Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            ws1.Cells(rowheader1, i).Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            On Error Resume Next
            If Not UCase(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) = "X" Then
                If UCase(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) = "ASCENDING" Then
                   With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List").AutoFilter.Sort
                        .SortFields.Add key:=Range(Cells(rowheader1, i), Cells(lastRowVal, i)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
                                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .Apply
                    End With
                    ws1.ApplyFilter

                ElseIf UCase(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) = "DESCENDING" Then
                    With ws1.AutoFilter.Sort
                        .SortFields.Add key:=Range(Cells(rowheader1, i), Cells(lastRowVal, i)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
                                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                        .Apply
                    End With
                    ws1.ApplyFilter

                 ElseIf UCase(ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter)) = "LAST" Then

                    ws1.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
                    ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=LastRow

                Else
                    ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=ws2.Cells(i + 1, columFilter).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i



    'close da shit
    If closefilter Then
       Call FileHandling.closeWorksheetFilter(wb2, ws2)
    End If

    ws1.Cells(1, 1).Select
    Set ws1 = Nothing
End Sub



Sub Unhide_All_Columns()

'Clears filters on the activesheet. Will not clear filters if the sheet is protected.
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.FilterMode Or ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If

     'in case the sheet is protected
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List").Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False


    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("All")).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = 50
    End With


    If Not ThisWorkbook.buttonActive = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ThisWorkbook.buttonActive)).Select
        With Selection.Font
            .ColorIndex = 1
        End With
    End If


    ThisWorkbook.buttonActive = "All"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("A1").Select

Protection:
If Err.Number = 1004 And Err.Description = _
    "ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed" Then
    'MsgBox "Unable to Clear Filters. This could be due to protection on the sheet.", _
    'vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to hide rows based on certain criteria. Is that correct? If so what is it you want to do?

Comment: I am using excel version 2016. @ScottHoltzman

Comment: Well when I have an excel sheet with something like 50 columns which we are 10 people working on it makes it hard to use, if I am not applying filter to it. So for one case i am interested in showing column E G I and then all rows in K which are not empty and sorted descending by column F. So in my filter sheet I have listed all columns A to ZZ in column A. Then in B1 I have the name of button(Delivery) then I just put X B6 B8 ..NOT EMPTY in B11 and DESCENDING in B16. Then my macro create a button Delivery and when i click this button it hides all column which are empty in B in my filter sheet